# How to prevent double callbacks during try...catch in javascript / nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, try-catch

Today I discovered an error in my code that leads to callbacks potentially being executed more than once. The intended usage of try...catch was meant for JSON.parse() operation; however, an error has occurred right after it inside the callback itself.

```
var body='{}';
var callback=function (arg){
    console.log('callback executed with arg='+arg);
    arg?    pack_michael(): pack_jolly();
}
try {
    JSON.parse(body); //if JSON parse successful should callback once with true argument
    callback(true);
} catch (e){
    callback(false);  //if JSON parse fails should callback once with false argument
}
```

Above code results in double callback printing this:

```
callback executed with arg=true
callback executed with arg=false
```

I can think of some ugly solutions like creating a variable and checking if an error has occurred or nesting another unnecessary try...catch, but isn't there any neat solution to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the callback *after* the `try`/`catch`:

```
let parseOk = false;
try {
    JSON.parse(body);
    parseOk = true;
} catch (e){
    // parseOk is already false
}
callback(parseOk);
```

If you also want to catch errors in the callback itself, you can surround it in a different `try`/`catch`, but that's *separate* from errors that occur in the `JSON.parse`, so they shouldn't be combined.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. It uses a variable, which I was opposing initially, but it does spare from adding callback in both sections with different arguments and only does it once. So, it's actually great and guess I'm going to stick with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add new `try/catch` around callback

```
try {
  JSON.parse(body);
  try {
    callback(true);
  } catch(err) { console.log("Error in callback")}
} catch (e){
  callback(false);  //if JSON parse fails should callback once with false argument
}
```